Check for "multiViewEnabled" in Flutter Web application from Flutter 3.0.0 until latest Version
I have a Flutter Web plugin where I need to support from Flutter 3.0.0 upwards to the latest Version.
In addition I have to handle things different if the User has set multiViewEnabled=true in the flutter_bootstrap.js, which was introduced recently Flutter 3.24.
Checking via PlatformDispatcher.instance.implicitView is not possible, because this feature was introduced with Flutter 3.10.0 in 2023.
I found out, that traditional Flutter Web Applications have two elements in the __flutterState variable. The first one is always meta and the second one is flutter-view.
Compared to this, a multiViewEnabled application doesn't have a meta object. It only has flutter-view elements for the number of active views.
My questions is, how reliable is to check for multiViewEnabled via the meta element in __flutterState?
Example: "meta" == js.context['__flutterState'][0].toString();
Is there another way to check if multiViewEnabled was set and make it backward compatible to Flutter 3.0.0?
Thanks in advance.
BR
